# After switching site to https, form submission stops working

Tags: nginx, https, html

I have a simple HTML form on my site:

```
<form action="/evaluation_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" id="submit-id-save">
</form>
```

My nginx config is:

```
# Default server
server {
    server_name _;
    return 404;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;

    # ssl cache settings
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 180m;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_certificate /letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DHE+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    location /uploads/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /uploads/;
    }

    location / {
        # prevent access for some bots
        if ($http_user_agent ~ (libwww|Wget|LWP|damnBot|BBBike|java|spider|crawl) ) {
            return 403;
        }

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

When submitting the form, nginx responds: *400 Bad Request. The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Open the debug tools in your browser, and in the network tab, watch what URL the POST is sent. Perhaps there's some javascript that is sending it to a non-https url.